# Are there any papers showing that too much learning matters is bad for memory?

Tags: learning, memory, mental-exhaustion

Does anyone know papers indicating that too much information is bad for the memory or even more precise - that too much learning matter is bad for the success of a student? I know a bit of the mechanism of how memory works (Papez circle, Hippocampus etc.) but not too much. So if there is any mechanism that also would indicate my hypothesis, could you help me with that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, welcome at CogSci. How did you come to this hypothesis? It would help others formulating an answer if they would understand your train of thought.

Comment: Maybe [retroactive interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_theory#Retroactive_interference)?

Comment: @Robin Kramer: I heard about the limited capacity control system, which helps us to focus on something.This system is not endless in his capacity.We need this system to absorb new information. If it is limited, there must be some limitation in the amount of learning matter we can process in a certain time frame. Another thought was that the hippocampus can be seen as a blackboard. We write something on the blackboard (episodic memory). Then this goes up to the cortex (semantisation of the episodic memory). I can imagine, that the blackboard is also not limitless which brings me to my question.

Comment: @S.Christensen adding that to your question to inform us precisely what your conception of memory and then proposing an experiment to test your concept would make this an excellent question that I would happily upvote

Comment: @Seanny123: Maybe this? Im trying to find other papers... It's not too easy for me because its not really my field.

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0079742108604521

Comment: @S.Christensen start at the [Wikipedia article for memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory) and specify based off the types of memory presented in the article, which one you are interested in.